# How to check whether date string is in "02 DEC 2014" this format?

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting a date in string type following format "02 DEC 2014". iam looking for a way to detect the string is valid date or not in swift? . I was expecting date in MM/dd/yyyy format and added the below code. but due to this "dd MMM yyyy format its not working now"

```
 func isValidDate(dateString: String) -> Bool {
        let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        if let _ = dateFormatterGet.date(from: dateString) {
            //date parsing succeeded, if you need to do additional logic, replace _ with some variable name i.e date
            return true
        } else {
            // Invalid date
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: am actually looking for a away that i can check if my string is  ddMMMyyyy then call another method

Comment: What does that comment mean, if it is relevant to the question then update the question rather than posting more information as a comment. If it is not relevant then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting strings in ***either*** `02/12/2014` or `12 DEC 2014` formats, there are a number of ways to check if the string is a valid date.

This might work for you:

```
func dateFromString(dateString: String) -> Date? {
    let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    if let d = dateFormatterGet.date(from: dateString) {
        return d
    }
    dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "dd MM yyy"
    if let d = dateFormatterGet.date(from: dateString) {
        return d
    }
    return nil
}
```

It will return either a `Date` object or `nil` if it cannot be parsed.

For example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var s: String = ""

    s = "12/02/2014"

    if let d = dateFromString(dateString: s) {
        print(s, "Is a Date:", d)
    } else {
        print(s, "Is NOT a valid Date in either `mm/dd/yyyy` or 'dd MM yyyy' format!")
    }

    s = "02 DEC 2014"

    if let d = dateFromString(dateString: s) {
        print(s, "Is a Date:", d)
    } else {
        print(s, "Is NOT a valid Date in either `mm/dd/yyyy` or 'dd MM yyyy' format!")
    }

}
```

Should output the following to the debug console:

> 12/02/2014 Is a Date: 2014-12-02 05:00:00 +0000
>
> 02 DEC 2014 Is a Date: 2014-12-02 05:00:00 +0000